# Where are structure objects stored in C?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, structure, heap-memory

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student_college_detail
{
 int college_id;
 char college_name[50];
}stud;


int main() 
{
    struct student_college_detail stud= {71145,"Anna University"};
    printf(" College Id is: %d \n",stud.college_id);
    printf(" College Name is: %s \n",stud.college_name);
    return 0;
}
```

For example in the above program where is the object **"stud"** stored in memory? Whether it is heap or stack?

Comment: Is the definition appearing inside a function, or outside?

Comment: @Keerthana You did not show where this declaration occurred..

Comment: All we can say is that it's not a heap-allocated variable, only dynamically allocated memory comes from "the heap". Otherwise it depends on *where* you define the structure object. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Nowhere. Here you are only defining it and not instantiating it.

Comment: @Ra'Jiska that would be true if there were a `typedef` before `struct`and then `stud` would be the type, but here `stud` is an instance of `struct student_college_detail`.

Comment: Since few people have asked for where the definition of stud is I have edited the sample code into a full sample program.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 1 An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime. There
>   are four storage durations: static, thread, automatic, and allocated.
>   Allocated storage is described in
>   7.22.3.

So for example if the object is declared in a function like main

```
int main( void )
{
    struct student_college_detail
    {
        int college_id;
        char college_name[50];
    } stud;

    //..
}
```

then it has the automatic storage duration and will not be alive after exiting the function. You may think that internally the object is created in the stack.

If the object declared outside any function (that is has external or internal linkage) or inside a function with the storage specifier static then it has the static storage duration and will be alive until the program finishes its execution.

```
struct student_college_detail
{
    int college_id;
    char college_name[50];
} stud;

int main( void )
{
    static struct student_college_detail
    {
        int college_id;
        char college_name[50];
    } stud;

    //..
}
```

The allocated storage duration means when an object is allocated using memory allocation function like `malloc`.  An object with the allocated storage duration is alive until it will be freed using the function free or the program finishes its execution. You may think that internally the object is created in the heap.

An object that is declared with the specifier `_Thread_local` has thread storage duration. From the same C standard section

> Its lifetime is the entire execution of the thread for which it is
>   created, and its stored value is initialized when the thread is
>   started.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare a variable like `stud` inside of a function this will be in that function stack.

if this `stud` is outside of a function (global variable) this will be placed in `Uninitialized data segment`.

if it was initialized then this would be in `Initialized data segment`.

only dynamically allocated memory variables will be placed in `heap` ,so as mentioned in comments this `stdu` won't be in `heap`.

`static` and `global` variables , if they are initialized ,they will be in `Initialized data segment` and if they are uninitialized they will be in 
 `Uninitialized data segment`.